# how to export environment variable using newman API

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, postman, newman

i'm running a postman test suit using newman api. Its executing properly as expected but i want to export environment variable generated during test execution in file, in command line it is possible using --export-environment:

```
newman run collectionPreReq.json -e Environment.json -k --export-environment newmanExport.json
```

for the same i'm writing javascript to get environment exported by collectionPreReq but not getting what i'm looking for, the code is

```
var newman = require('newman');

newman.run({
    collection: require('./collectionPreReq.json'),
    //reporters: 'cli',
    environment: require('./Environment.json'),
    insecure: true
}).on('start', function (err, args) {
    console.log('running a collection...');
}).on('done', function (err, summary) {
    if (err || summary.error) {
        console.error('collection run encountered an error.');
    }
    else {
        console.log('collection run completed.:');
        console.log("summary environment :");
        console.log(summary.environment);
    }
});
```

Output:

```
running a collection...
collection run completed.:
summary environment :
{ object: [Function], toJSON: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use this newman option **exportEnvironment: require('./Environment.json')** in the javascript file like

```
newman.run({
   collection: require('./collectionPreReq.json'),
   //reporters: 'cli',
   environment: require('./Environment.json'),
   exportEnvironment: require('./Environment.json'),
   insecure: true 
})....
```

Surely, This statement will work.

Comment: If environment is not there, and postman can run without it. If we leave it blank does it run? I am asking since iam creating an generic node js script to run postman collection, with or without the environment file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not possible per [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env).

> The process.env property returns an object containing the user
>   environment. See environ(7).
>
> An example of this object looks like:

```
{ 
  TERM: 'xterm-256color', 
  SHELL: '/usr/local/bin/bash', 
  USER: 'maciej', 
  PATH: '~/.bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin', 
  PWD: '/Users/maciej', 
  EDITOR: 'vim', 
  SHLVL: '1', 
  HOME: '/Users/maciej',   
  LOGNAME: 'maciej',   
  _: '/usr/local/bin/node' 
}
```

> It is possible to modify this object, but such modifications will not be
>   reflected outside the Node.js process. In other words, the following
>   example would not work:
>
> `$ node -e 'process.env.foo = "bar"' && echo $foo`

Answer (score 0):

To console log the actual environment variables you'd need to stringify the JSON first:
.....

```
.on('done', function (err, summary) {
if (err || summary.error) {
console.error('collection run encountered an error.');
}
else {
console.log('collection run completed.:');
console.log("summary environment :");
console.log(JSON.stringify(summary.environment))
}
});
```